# setInterval props don't update

Tags: meteor, redux, react-redux

i dispatch action in the code below. And in the action i have loggingIn === false, but this.props.loggingIn === true. 
How to fix it?

**component.js**

```
updateProfile() {
    return { user: Meteor.user(), loggingIn: Meteor.loggingIn() }
}


componentWillMount() {
    this.props.loadUser(this.updateProfile());
    debugger;
    this.data = setInterval(() => {
        if(this.props.loggingIn === true) {
            this.props.loadUser(this.updateProfile());
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

**actions.js**

```
export const loadUser = ({user, loggingIn}) => dispatch => {
dispatch({
    type: 'USER_DATA',
    payload: user
})
dispatch({
    type: 'USER_LOGGING_IN',
    payload: loggingIn
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using redux-thunk for async calls. Here is the tutorial for using [redux-thunk](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators)
and an example code for handling user [authentication in Meteor](https://github.com/ganesshkumar/tasks/blob/master/client/actions/authActions.js#L71)